# Animate Header in ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-animation

I want to add a header to my list view that will appear when I scroll up and disappear when I scroll down. This functionality is in the Facebook app. Is there any component in the ListView that I can call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are comfortable using 3rd party libraries, here's a great one based on what you want.
https://github.com/LarsWerkman/QuickReturnListView

Also, I would really suggest you to take a look at Libraries for developers app. https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.desarrollodroide.repos
Very much useful for us developers! I happen to stumble upon a lot of useful libraries from this app!